# Как правильно передать реферальную политику на сайт?

Tags: python, бот, qiwi

Всем привет. Хочу передать (исправить реф. политику https://qiwi.com/support/products/p2p/referalnie_ssylki) реферальную ссылку для оплаты счета, пробую добавить заголовок (результат №1), в консоли всё ок, копирую ссылку, и ничего не меняется :(
Прошу помощи.

```
    # Для выставления счёта
secret_key = '  '
p2p = QiwiP2P(auth_key = secret_key)
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update({'Referrer-Policy': 'no-referrer-when-downgrade'})
url = p2p.bill(amount = 1, lifetime = 30).pay_url
#s.post(url) - ошибка 403!
print(url)
print(s.headers)
```

Скорее всего я что-то делаю не так https://pythonru.com/biblioteki/kratkoe-rukovodstv...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/qiwi-wallet-personal/?http#errors

Например:

```
head = {'Referrer-Policy': 'no-referrer-when-downgrade'}
r = requests.post("https://httpbin.org/post", headers = head)
print(r.text)
```

подключаюсь к сайту, передаю реф. политику, но document.referre все ровно возвращает пустую строку и заголовок не добавился((
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]